# How to decode the base64 string which is not four times the length of string by using vb.net？

Tags: vb.net

I have to decode base64 string for my job, I used "Convert.FromBase64String", but it occured
error "System.FormatException" - Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

How to solve it?

How to decode the base64 string which is not four times the length of string by using vb.net？

Comment: Is it a valid base64 string?

Comment: no, it`s true base64 string, but thestring length not four times. I have to decode it for my job.

Comment: Can you show an example of your base64 string which is not working?

Comment: Are you sure you're not cutting off (some of) the padding, i.e. = or == from the BASE64 string?

Comment: Why should a base64 string be 4 times the original string? What encoder was used to generate the bytes? What are you passing the result of `Convert.FromBase64String()` to?

Comment: A base64 string does not have to be "4" times the original length, but is usually a multiple of four.  Most base64 libraries allow dropping the padding ("=" or "==") through a special option.  However, if the length is 1 (mod 4), that's always an invalid base64 string because there are not enough bits to make a full byte.

Comment: I can't actually find a method in dotnet that allows not using the padding, but you can always restore it yourself by appending "=" or "==" to make the string length a multiple of four.

Answer (score 0):

This Class is An Example of Base64String Encode/Decode:

**'StreamImage' Class**

```
Public Class StreamImage
     Shared Function FromString(ByVal Value$) As Image
         Dim M As IO.Stream, Img As Image
        M = New IO.MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(Value))
        M.Position = 0
    Img = If(M Is Nothing, Nothing, Image.FromStream(M))
    M.Close
    Return Img
    End Function
     Shared Function FromFile$(ByVal file$)
         Return Convert.ToBase64String(IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file))
     End Function
 End Class
```

---

**Convert an Image file to Base64String and Save to Text File:**

```
Dim StringStream$ = ""
StringStream = StreamImage.FromFile("{ImageFilePath}")
Io.File.WriteAllText("{TextFilePath}", StringStream)
```

---

**Recover Saved Base64String from the Text file and Convert to Image:**

```
Dim StringStrm$ = ""
StringStrm = Io.File.ReadAllText("{TextFilePath}")
PictureBox1.Image = StreamImage.FromString(StringStrm)
```

Good luck.