# Simulating Java Base64Url.decode by using Visual Basic

Tags: java, vb.net

I use Visual Basic to Simulate java program language Base64Url.decode, this is my code:

Java

```
import org.jose4j.base64url.Base64Url;
public class ss {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Base64str = "q128qjafnAdcbkfrhfWim783bCvDWsak9bfe2ERjnAc";
        byte[] decodeResult = Base64Url.decode(Base64str);
    }
}
```

Visual Basic

```
Dim Base64str As String = "q128qjafnAdcbkfrhfWim783bCvDWsak9bfe2ERjnAc"
Dim decodeResult() As Byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Base64str)
```

It showed System.FormatException - Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

How to solve it?

Comment: Your base64 string has an invalid length, i.e. the padding is missing. It should be `q128qjafnAdcbkfrhfWim783bCvDWsak9bfe2ERjnAc=`. I assume VB is more strict than the 3rd party library you're using in Java (note that `org.jose4j.base64url.Base64Url` is _not_ a standard library class).

Comment: Perhaps try: `Dim decodeResult As Byte() = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Base64str)`.

Comment: You have [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74273756/7444103) this question, the problem is still the same. Where is this Base64 string coming from? What is it supposed to represent?